# Is there any alternative to Netflix Photon library for validating IMF packages?

Tags: java, xml, validation, schema

I am validating [IMF packages](http://www.telestream.net/pdfs/datasheets/App-brief-Vantage-IMF.pdf) in Java and i want to use a new version of [CPL](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7290378) which uses the namespace xmlns:cc="[http://www.smpte-ra.org/ns/2067-2/2020](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9097478)".
It seems that Netflix Photon([even latest version 4.8.0](https://github.com/Netflix/photon/tree/feature/IMF2020)) -  is only supporting the below two CPL schema URIs(supportedCPLSchemaURIs constant in code):

> 1. http://www.smpte-ra.org/schemas/2067-3/2013
> 2. http://www.smpte-ra.org/schemas/2067-3/2016

When i try to validate the CPL i am getting the following error:

> Please check the CPL document and namespace URI, currently we only
> support the following schema URIs
> http://www.smpte-ra.org/schemas/2067-3/2013
> http://www.smpte-ra.org/schemas/2067-3/2016  [Photon version: 4.8.0]

I was not able to find solution for the above.

Is there any alternative library which can bypass the above error?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of tools available from vendors who validate against the actual SMPTE specification. Photon is Netflix specific.